# Cannot login to website using a macro and vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to login to a website using the following which works on different url

```
Sub Mylogin()

    Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MyURL As String
    On Error GoTo Err_Clear
    MyURL = "MYURL"
    ie.Silent = True
    ie.Navigate MyURL
    ie.Visible = True
    Do
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Set HTMLDoc1 = ie.Document
        HTMLDoc1.all.Email.Value = "MYEMAIL" 'Enter your email id here
        HTMLDoc1.all.Password.Value = "MYPASSWD" 'Enter your password here
        For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc1.getElementsByTagName("input")
            If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
        Next
        Err_Clear:
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
        End If

End Sub
```

The submit button is under div and I dont know if this is the problem. The html login part is the following

```
<div id="login-area-main">
       <div id="user">
            <div id="username">
            <input name="p$lt$ctl01$LogonFormIndice$loginElem$UserName" type="text" maxlength="50" id="p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_UserName" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <span class="CMSValidator"><span id="p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_rfvUserNameRequired" title="Please enter a user name." class="profile-validator validator error-message" style="display:none;">
            </span></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pass">
            <div id="password">
            <input name="p$lt$ctl01$LogonFormIndice$loginElem$Password" type="password" maxlength="20" id="p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_Password" placeholder="Password" />
            <span class="CMSValidator"><span id="p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_rfvPasswordRequired" class="profile-validator validator error-message" style="visibility:hidden;">
            </span></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pass-forgot">
            <p><a href="/Special-Pages/ForgotPassword">Forgot Password</a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="submit-button">
            <a id="p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_btnLogon" class="buyBtn button" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;p$lt$ctl01$LogonFormIndice$loginElem$btnLogon&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_MiniLogon&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))"></a>
            </div>
```

Do I have to do something with

```
MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit"
```

And put inside the div id?

I notice that the HTMLDoc1 is Empty..! should it be empty?

I tried the following but nothing displayed or clicked

```
Const Url$ = "URL"

Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")
UserName = LoginData.Cells(1, "K").Value
Password = LoginData.Cells(2, "K").Value

Dim iex As Object
Set iex = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With iex

    .Navigate Url
    ieBusy iex
    .Visible = True
    Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
    iex.Document.querySelector(".username [id='p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_UserName']").Focus
    Set oLogin = iex.Document.querySelector(".username [id='p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_UserName']").Value = ""
    Set oPassword = iex.Document.querySelector(".password [type=password]").Value = ""

    oLogin.Value = UserName
    oPassword.Value = Password
    iex.Document.getElementById("submit-button").Click

End With
```

It asks about an Object on

```
iex.Document.querySelector("id='p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_UserName']").Focus
```

Comment: Have you tried `HTMLDoc1.getElementById("p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_btnLogon").Click`?

Comment: Does `HTMLDoc1.all.Email.Value = "MYEMAIL"` actually work?

Comment: No It shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused by where your actual problem is.

There is an id for the submit

```
ie.document.getElementById("submit-button").click   ' 0r .submit
```

For username:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[id='p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_UserName']").value = ""
```

For password

```
ie.document.querySelector("[type=password]").value = ""
```

When entering values it sometimes helps to use `.Focus` on the element before assigning the `.value`.

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document.querySelector("[id='p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_UserName']")
            .Focus
            .value = ""
        End With
        With .document.querySelector("[type=password]")
            .Focus 
            .value = ""
        End With
        .document.getElementById("submit-button").click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Stop
        'Quit 
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that the fields are not filled yes maybe they need focus first (have not tried it yet and the submit button was not cliked. If I leave it like this and comment the errors it displays error that needs an Object..Can you please show me a complete example of your correct approach?

Comment: So your code is filling the fields for username and password but you can’t click the submit?

Comment: Neither are filled or submit cliked

Comment: I need to do it like this? HTMLDoc1.all.Email.Focus
'HTMLDoc1.all.Email.Value = "Email" 'Enter your email id here
ie.Document.querySelector("[id='p_lt_ctl01_LogonFormIndice_loginElem_UserName']").Value = "Email"
HTMLDoc1.all.Password.Focus
'HTMLDoc1.all.Password.Value = "Passwd" 'Enter your password here
ie.Document.querySelector("[type=password]").Value = "Passwd"
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc1.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then ie.Document.getElementById("submit-button").Click: Exit For
Next